# want to toggle checkbox label using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Just a basic one im struggling with but:

I want the user to be able to toggle the `checkbox` label. at the moment its set to "**compare**", when they click it, the text should changed to "**added**". if they click it again, it should go back to normal. this is what ive done so far.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".visible").on("click", (event) => {
        // $(this).text($(this).text() == "added" ? "Compare" : "added");
        $("label").text("Item added");
    }).on("click", (event) => {
        $(event.currentTarget).addClass(".visible");
    })
});
```

html:

```
<div class="">
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" value=""><label for="toggle" class ="visible">Add to compare</label>
</div>
```

the text changes when they click but:

1. its not possible to change back so im missing something in my code
2. it affects all checkboxes, im unsure how to properly connect the event.current target to it.

any help would be nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #1, your commented-out code wasn't doing the toggle correctly because the `this` pointer jQuery sets when using ES5 doesn't work the same when using the ES6 `() => {}` function construct. Using `$(event.currentTarget)` instead of `$(this)` does what you're looking for there.

The reason #2 is happening is because your `$('label')` selector will always select all of the labels in the document. Using `$(event.currentTarget)` instead should fix that there as well.

The following snippet got things toggling when I tried it:

*(NOTE: I cleaned this up since the original post to reduce repeated code for readability.)*

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $(".visible").on("click", (event) => {
        // (Store the jQuery-wrapped currentTarget HTML element in a variable for better readability here.)
        let $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        $target.text($target.text() === "added" ? "Compare" : "added");
    }).on("click", (event) => {
        $(event.currentTarget).addClass("visible"); // << also don't want the "." before visible here ... this string is already a class name, not a selector string
    })
});
```

**A little more explanation since you asked:**

From your example, you already know that inside of any jQuery event callback that receives an `event` parameter -- like both of your handlers above -- `event.currentTarget` points to the HTML element that the event pertains to.

If you are using the ECMAScript5 (pre-ES6) form of the function callback, jQuery also makes sure the `this` pointer is set to `event.currentTarget` for convenience.

For convenience, jQuery also binds the `this` pointer to point to whatever `event.currentTarget` is so that you can do things like this without needing to type out `event.currentTarget` every time:

```
$("button").on("click", function(event) {
    // Using ES5 function() {} form, this === event.currentTarget
    $(this).prop('value', 'hi!');
});
```

There's another example of this [in the jQuery docs on event.currentTarget here](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/).

... but from your example -- if you use ES6's special construct for an inline function declaration (`(event) => {}`), ES6 does its own convenience-thing and goes ahead and pre-binds `this` to whatever the `this` context was when you set up the callback -- which it looks like is `this === window` (your global `window` context) in your sample code. And jQuery can't re-bind it back to the HTML element -- not even if it wanted to.

So **essentially, if you use the ES6 `()=>{}` form, you can't rely on `this` pointing to your element anymore**.

Another subtlety to notice is that `event.currentTarget` is the raw HTML element, and not the jQuery-wrapped one with all of jQuery's event-binder methods, etc. To get those, you have to wrap the element with `$()` to make it jQuery-ready. Same goes for `this` when using ES5 `function() {}` form: to get jQuery functionality you have to wrap it first.

```
$("button").on("click", function(event) {
    // These will work -- and will be equivalent since we're getting called back using the ES5 "function() {}" construct.
    $(this).prop('value', 'hi!');
    $(event.currentTarget).prop('value', 'hi!');

    // But these will both throw an exception because they're referring to raw HTML elements, and not jQuery-wrapped HTML objects:
    this.prop('value', 'hi!');
    event.currentTarget.prop('value', 'hi!');
});
```

Of course there's nothing at all wrong with using the ES6 `() => {}` construct -- you just need to be aware that `this` works differently w/ jQuery when using it.

Also note that a lot of people like to prefix variables that represent jQuery-wrapped elements with a `$` like this:

```
let $button = $('#my-form button');
```

... So from there on out, it's obvious that `$button` is an HTML element that has already been wrapped as a jQuery object.

Finally, it's also harmless to keep re-wrapping any jQuery element inside another `$()` wrapper -- jQuery just returns the wrapper itself:

```
let $button = $('#my-form button');
let $button2 = $($button);

// jQuery objects wrap the HTML element, but make it available in an array (since jQuery queries can return > 1) elements.
if ($button[0] === $button2[0]) {
    console.info('These are still the same element');
}
```

Comment: thank you that did work. just so i properly understand, can you possible explain your code please? like how you used the ternary operators i.e. ? and :. also why you combined the event.current target like that. because ive used code academy and in my mind couldnt understand how to use event.current.target in situations like that.

Comment: Sure. Added a more-verbose explanation above & cleaned up my code to make it a bit more readable.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add/remove a class to identify whether it's toggled or not, something like this:

```
$(".visible").on("click", function() {
    var itemid = $(this).attr('id');
    if($("#"+itemid+" label").hasClass("added")){
        $("#"+itemid+" label").html("Compare");
        $("#"+itemid+" label").removeClass("added");
    } else {
        $("#"+itemid+" label").html("Added");
        $("#"+itemid+" label").addClass("added");
    }
});
```